# How to sign transaction externally?

Tags: wallet, transaction, cardano-serialization-lib, cbor, ed25519

I am using the cardano-serialization-lib to derive addresses and create a transaction unsigned. I am then passing that transaction hash in CBOR to an external program to handle the signing process. I am unsure how that works because with the library, we sign the transaction by creating a new Transaction Object, passing in the witnesses and body of the previous transaction. See below

```
const signed_transaction = await cardanolib.Transaction.new(
  newTx.body(),
  witnesses,
  undefined //metadata
);
```

I want to to this on my own, but I'm not sure exactly what gets signed. I have tried signing the transaction body with the curve25519 algorithm, but I am getting a different hash from that transaction made this way. I am not sure if I am understanding how the signing process works for the transaction. What exactly gets signed and how do I create that transaction?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Might have to go through the node source code :-/

Comment: @noone392 yes I found a solution. it works the same way as the signing works in an all hot implementation with CSL. Ill give you a hint, there exists some function to grab the hash and you have to go about making the witnesses object yourself. Going to require you to step through the source code a bit, but nothing crazy.